# How do I declare a 2 digit integer in an array? So I would not have to write it out

Tags: c#

How do I declare a 2 digit integer in an array? So I would not have to write it out because I got to have a point system from 1 to 60 that needs to be recorded

```
int[] strScore = new int[60] {1, 2, 3, /*...,*/ 59, 60};
```

Comment: do you mean `int[] strScore = new int[60] {1, 2, 3, /*...,*/ 59, 60};`?  Don't mean to be pedantic, but the array of `int`s instantiated with `string`s makes your example a little confusing

Comment: hmm sorry to be confusing I am new to programming and just trying to get a concept on arrays, so I am practicing.

Answer (score 4):

If you trying to generate all the numbers between 1 and 60 without declaring them explicitly.

Try:

```
int[] scores = Enumerable.Range(1, 60).ToArray();
```

Comment: Awesome Thanks! Now do I just use a regular If Statement if I am trying to set a range mean the User cannot enter anything less than 1 or more than 60?